# How can I select a XLFormRowDescriptor in an XLForm programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xlform

I'm using the XLForm cocoapod, and I'm trying to figure out how I can programmatically select a XLFormRowDescriptor in an XLForm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your UIViewController needs to be a subclass of XLFormViewController.  There is a property, "form", on the XLFormViewController.  This "form" is of type XLFormDescriptor which has multiple methods for retrieving XLFormRowDescriptors on the form.

formRowWithTag
formRowAtIndex
formRowWithHash